# Updating formData being grabbed from local storage

Tags: reactjs

I am currently storing the value a user submits via a form that sets an item in localStorage, which tells me how many items a user wants to display. When a user submits the form it sets the limit amount in local storage.  I am then trying to fetch and display that local storage value as my select's value. The limit is being set in local storage fine, but when I click away from the page and go back, whatever was set in localStorage is not being displayed, the old value is.  I have to refresh the browser for the changes to take effect and it is confusing the hell out of me.  the code is as follows:

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

// components
import NewJobForm from '../components/NewJobForm'
import JobCard from '../components/JobCard'
import Fab from '@material-ui/core/Fab'
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add'
import Alert from '../components/Alert'
import SelectLimit from '../components/SelectLimit'

// Material UI Stuff
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress'
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container'
import useMediaQuery from '@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery'
import Modal from '@material-ui/core/Modal'
import Backdrop from '@material-ui/core/Backdrop'
import Fade from '@material-ui/core/Fade'
import Snackbar from '@material-ui/core/Snackbar'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'

// context
import { ProfileContext } from '../contexts/ProfileContext'

// JobCardStyles
import useJobCardStyles from '../styles/JobCardStyles'

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  company: '',
  position: '',
  link: '',
  status: '',
  limit: localStorage.Limit ? localStorage.Limit : ''
}

const Alumni = () => {
  const classes = useJobCardStyles()
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(INITIAL_STATE)




  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('im running')
    console.log(localStorage.Limit)
    localStorage.Limit && localStorage.getItem('Limit')
  }, [])


  const fetchNext = async e => {
    localStorage.setItem('Limit', `${formData.limit}`)
    e.preventDefault()
    const token = await localStorage.FBIdToken
    const number = formData.limit

    await axios
      .get(`/user?limit=${number}`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `${token}`
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        setUser(res.data)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }


  const handleInputChange = field => e => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [field]: e.target.value })
  }

  return (

      {user && user.jobs.length === 0 ? (
        <p></p>
      ) : (
        <form noValidate onSubmit={fetchNext} className={classes.form}>
          <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="center" justify="center">
      <Grid item sm={2} xs={12} className={classes.grid}>
              <FormControl style={{ width: '100%', textAlign: 'center' }}>
                <Select
                  labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
                  id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
                  value={formData.limit}
                  onChange={handleInputChange('limit')}
                >
                  <MenuItem value="5">5 Results</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="10">10 Results</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="20">20 Results</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="50">50 Results</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="100">100 Results</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="1000000">All Results</MenuItem>
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item sm={2} xs={12} className={classes.grid}>
              <Button
                type="submit"
                fullWidth
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                disableElevation
                className={classes.submit}
              >
                Set Limit
              </Button>
            </Grid>


          </Grid>
        </form>
      )}
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Alumni
```

Answer (score 0):

exist several solutions of your problem.

The first, if you want to set data to redux store, and sync redux value with localStorage and restore after page refreshing automatically, you can use [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) library, which persist and rehydrate a redux store.

The second solution is don't use redux or any other state management library. You can temporary store it for example in session storage. And restore it on mount of form. The details you can see [here](https://youtu.be/-j8s0RNOZ8U)